# update multiple array values with multiple ids in laravel 5.1

Tags: arrays, laravel-5.1

My query as follows

```
        $dueid = array('1','2');

        for($n = 0; $n< count($post['percentage']); $n++) {

            $due=invoiceduedates::whereIn('id',$dueid)
            ->update(array(
            'percentage' => $post['percentage'][$n],
            'amount'=>$post['pamount'][$n],
            'date' => $post['date'][$n]

            )
            );

        }
```

But in table,at 1st and 2nd ids the 2nd array data is getting updated.Please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you what to get... but in this way it's normal that you get what you get. I can only sugest you to try like this:

```
$dueid = array('1','2');
$dues = invoiceduedates::whereIn('id',$dueid)->get();

for($n = 0; $n< count($post['percentage']); $n++) {
        $due = $dues->find($dueid[$n+1]);

        $due->update(array(
                'percentage' => $post['percentage'][$n],
                'amount'=>$post['pamount'][$n],
                'date' => $post['date'][$n]
            )
    );

}
```